# Using mysql to find common set between two lists

Tags: mysql, percentage, set-difference

I have two queries in which I would like to find their common values. I'm trying to ultimately find out what percentage of users have visited both webpages.

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id 
FROM table 
WHERE url ='y'
ORDER BY user_id;

SELECT DISTINCT user_id 
FROM table 
WHERE url ='z'
ORDER BY user_id;
```

I've tried a

```
NOT IN
```

and a

```
UNION
```

but haven't had much luck - though I could easily be doing it wrong. I'm new.

Comment: do you want find percentage such users from all users or from those who visited at least one page ?

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use conditional aggregation.  To get information for each user:

```
select user_id,
       sum(url = 'y') as y_visits,
       sum(url = 'z') as z_visits
from t
group by user_id;
```

To get the list of users, add a `having` clause:

```
having y_visits >= 1 and z_visits >- 1
```

To get summary information:

```
select y_visitor, z_visitor, count(*)
from (select user_id,
             max(url = 'y') as y_visitor,
             max(url = 'z') as z_visitor
      from t
      group by user_id
     ) yz
group by y_visitor, z_visitor;
```

To get a simple percentage:

```
select avg(y_visitor = 1 and z_visitor = 1) as p_VisitedBothYandZ
from (select user_id,
             max(url = 'y') as y_visitor,
             max(url = 'z') as z_visitor
      from t
      group by url
     ) yz;
```